# Вызов функции в опциях

Tags: jquery

Нужно вызвать функцию в опциях плагина, так не работает

```
 function randomInteger(min, max) {
  var rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}

....

bold : {
                    title: CURLANG.bold,
                    buttonHTML: '<span class="fonticon ve-tlb-bold1">\uE018</span>',
                    excmd: 'bold',
                    hotkey: 'ctrl+b',
                    transform : {
                        '<b='+randomInteger(1, 99999)+'>{SELTEXT}</b>':"[b]{SELTEXT}[/b]"
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Ключ объекта не выражение; конкатенация, вычисления и пр. не поддерживаются.

Comment: @Other, делать то что?

Comment: @Other, в es2015 - поддерживаются

Comment: @Rammsteinik, [`var o = {
  [prop]: "hey"}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: @Grundy, интерполяция выражения - это не ключ. Хотя да, про эту фичу забыл.

Comment: @Other, не понял про _интерполяция выражения - это не ключ_

Comment: @Grundy, ну скобки заставляют вычислить выражение и поставить полученное как ключ. Вроде как.

Comment: @Other, Тогда почему это не ключ? :)

Comment: @Grundy, это **будет** ключом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, единственный способ получить объект, который вы хотите - собрать его по шагам:

```
var bold = {
  title: CURLANG.bold,
  buttonHTML: '<span class="fonticon ve-tlb-bold1">\uE018</span>',
  excmd: 'bold',
  hotkey: 'ctrl+b',
  transform: {}
}

bold.transform['<b=' + randomInteger(1, 99999) + '>{SELTEXT}</b>'] = "[b]{SELTEXT}[/b]"
```

.

*Чуть позже...*

Нет, оказывается, можно написать так:

```js
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  var rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
  rand = Math.round(rand);
  return rand;
}

var bold = {
  title: 'CURLANG.bold',
  buttonHTML: '<span class="fonticon ve-tlb-bold1">\uE018</span>',
  excmd: 'bold',
  hotkey: 'ctrl+b',
  transform: {
    ['<b=' + randomInteger(1, 99999) + '>{SELTEXT}</b>']: "[b]{SELTEXT}[/b]"
  }
}

console.log(bold);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexey_m_ukolov/wk4v77sn/1/

Comment: Всё верно, не подскажите, как вставить этот randomInteger(1, 99999) в 2 разных места, типа `['<b=' + rnd + '>{SELTEXT}</b=' + rnd + '>']: "[b]{SELTEXT}[/b]"` чтоб выдавал одинаковые значения. Определить переменную не вышло

Comment: @Rammsteinik, покажите код, в котором у вас _не вышло_